# Ruby Autocompletion (pry gem) in Spacemacs/Emacs

Tags: ruby, emacs, autocomplete, pry, spacemacs

I've started to use Spacemacs and I have a trouble with ruby autocompletion. When Gemfile contains `pry` autocompletion works fine, but if `pry` is not present in the Gemfile, I get the error `cannot load such file -- pry` after `:robe-start` or `SPC m s i`. I don't want to add unnecessary gems to the Gemfile and looking for the solution to use globally installed `pry`.

I researched and found the next solutions: Add `Pry.config.eager_load!` to `.pryrc` or add `pry` to global gemset but any of them did not help.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Yes, I'm using RVM, and `pry` installed in all ruby versions.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi I'm sorry for the stupid question (I'm newby in emacs), but how to evaluate this `(executable-find "pry")` in spacemacs? In emacs this is `M-:` but in spacemacs thats not works.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi `(executable-find "pry")` shows me path to the `pry`

Comment: Yes, I'm using `robe`. Anyway thanks for Your help.